# How to access variable by its name

Tags: ruby, local-variables

How can I access variable by its name?

```
a = Hash.new
a["test"] = 9
some_method(:a) # => {"test" => 9}
```

Comment: Does this help? `a = 7; binding.local_variable_get(:a) #=> 7` or `eval("a")
 #=> 7`.

Comment: There is a 99% probability this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = Hash.new
a["test"] = 9
binding.local_variable_get(:a) # => {"test"=>9}
```

Comment: Or you can use eval method ofc.